# Why is an idle Java thread showing high CPU usage?

Tags: java, multithreading, wildfly, cpu-usage, jstack

I'm using Wildfly 11 with JDK 8 on Amazon Linux.  I'm trying to figure out why a thread that is supposedly waiting is showing high CPU usage.  I got the PID of my application server process like so

```
[jboss@prodmachine ~]$ ps -elf | grep java
0 S jboss     8844     1  0  80   0 - 28275 wait   15:30 ?        00:00:00 /bin/sh /usr/java/wildfly/bin/standalone.sh -c standalone.xml
0 S jboss     8896  8844 99  80   0 - 7337773 futex_ 15:30 ?      08:16:14 /usr/java/default/bin/java -D[Standalone] -server -Xms64m -Xmx25600m -XX:MetaspaceSize=96M -XX:MaxMetaspaceSize=1024m -Djava.net.preferIPv4Stack=true -Djboss.modules.system.pkgs=org.jboss.byteman,com.newrelic -Djava.awt.headless=true -javaagent:/usr/java/wildfly/newrelic/newrelic.jar -Dorg.jboss.boot.log.file=/usr/java/wildfly/standalone/log/server.log -Dlogging.configuration=file:/usr/java/wildfly/standalone/configuration/logging.properties -jar /usr/java/wildfly/jboss-modules.jar -mp /usr/java/wildfly/modules org.jboss.as.standalone -Djboss.home.dir=/usr/java/wildfly -Djboss.server.base.dir=/usr/java/wildfly/standalone -c standalone.xml
```

and then I looked up the high Cpu uprocesses related to that

```
top -n 1 -H -p 8896

  PID USER      PR  NI  VIRT  RES  SHR S %CPU %MEM    TIME+  COMMAND                                                                           
 9310 jboss     20   0 28.0g 4.4g  33m S 43.3 15.2   3:16.72 java                                                                               
 9207 jboss     20   0 28.0g 4.4g  33m S 13.8 15.2  42:00.05 java                                                                               
 9292 jboss     20   0 28.0g 4.4g  33m S 13.8 15.2   3:17.87 java
```

So the hex for "9310" is "0x245e" and when I did a thread dump with jstack that's what I looked for ...

```
[jboss@prodmachine ~]$ /usr/lib/jvm/java-1.8.0-openjdk-1.8.0.181-8.b13.39.39.amzn1.x86_64/bin/jstack -l 8896 > /tmp/jstack.txt
```

revealed this

```
"default task-86" #272 prio=5 os_prio=0 tid=0x00000000090ee800 nid=0x245e waiting on condition [0x00007f3220cee000]
   java.lang.Thread.State: WAITING (parking)
        at sun.misc.Unsafe.park(Native Method)
        - parking to wait for  <0x0000000181c9e050> (a java.util.concurrent.locks.AbstractQueuedSynchronizer$ConditionObject)
        at java.util.concurrent.locks.LockSupport.park(LockSupport.java:175)
        at java.util.concurrent.locks.AbstractQueuedSynchronizer$ConditionObject.await(AbstractQueuedSynchronizer.java:2039)
        at java.util.concurrent.LinkedBlockingQueue.take(LinkedBlockingQueue.java:442)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.getTask(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1074)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1134)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
```

but everything I've read indicates that threads int he "WAITING" state should take up no CPU resources.  So why am I seeing this bizarre result?  Did I screw something up along the way?

Comment: `park` means the thread is suspended and not using CPU. Are there no RUNNABLE threads going? Also, take a look at the heap and see if the GC is moving a lot. Basically, there is not enough information to determine what your issue is.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of using the command line to monitor your threads activities, use Java visual VM it's pretty much better and will extremely help you.

**Does threads int the "WAITING" or "SLEEPING" state use CPU?**

There is time taken to enter and exit the sleep/waiting state. This is cost is relatively small but non-trivial if called enough.

In the case of wait(), it can wake spuriously so if you using it in a loop as is idiomatic, this could burn quite a bit of CPU in theory. In practice, this happen rarely in my experience but often enough that if you forget to use a loop it can create hard to reproduce bugs.

Comment: The java visual VM is under your JDK 1.8 folder => follow this path and execute it: **jdk1.8.x => bin => jvisualvm.exe**

Comment: We are using Amazon Linux and have SSH access only.  Visual stuff is not an easy option unless there is somethign I'm misunderstanding about shells.